# Change default legend in ggcompetingrisks to group-status combination

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival

I have the following competing risk plot that I want to format.
[image: Competing risk plot of two events with randomised data]

This is the example code for it.

```
set.seed(10) 
ftime <- runif(125, min = 0.1, max = 10)
fstatus <- factor(sample(rep(0:2, times = round(c(74/125, 40/125, 11/125) * 125)),
                         size = 125, replace = TRUE))
group <- factor(sample(rep(0:1, times = round(c(107/125, 18/125) * 125)),
                       size = 125, replace = TRUE))

cm <- cuminc(ftime = ftime, fstatus = fstatus, group = group)

ggcr <- ggcompetingrisks(cm,
                         censor = FALSE,
                         conf.int = FALSE,
                         multiple_panels = FALSE,
                         gnames = c("CIR Event1", "CIR Event2", "NRM Event1", "NRM Event2"),
                         xlim = c(0,10),
                         ylim = c(0, 1.0),
                         xlab = "Time (Years)",
                         ylab = "Cum. Risk",
                         title = "",
                         legend.title = "",
                         legend.fond = 16,
                         palette = c("red3", "royalblue3")
)


CIR_plot <- ggpar(ggcr + geom_line(linewidth = 1) + 
                    scale_y_continuous(label = c("0,00", "0,25", "0,50", "0,75", "1,00"),
                                       breaks = c(0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0)) +
                    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:10),
                  font.main = c(14),
                  font.x = c(14),
                  font.y = c(14),
                  font.caption = c(14), 
                  font.legend = c(12), 
                  font.tickslab = c(12))
```

I would like to change the legend so that I can see Event1 CIR (red continous), Event1 NRM (red dotted), Event2 CIR (blue continous) and Event2 NRM (blue dotted). I need to do this as a revision of my work, that's why I would like to change as little as I can on the existing plot. However, unfortunatley I haven't been able to find a solution for this in ggcompetingrisk/ggplot.

Is there an "easy to implement" solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to overwrite the mapping via `aes()`, i.e. map the interaction of `group` and `event` on both `colour` and `linetype` then set the colors and linetypes via `scale_color_manual` and `scale_linetype_manual`:

```
library(survminer)
library(cmprsk)

CIR_plot +
  aes(
    x = time, y = est,
    color = paste(event, group),
    linetype = paste(event, group)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = rep(c("red3", "royalblue3"), each = 2),
    name = NULL
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = rep(c("solid", "dotted"), 2),
    name = NULL
  )
```

[image]